# Data type conversion in list comprehension (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, types, custom-data-type

I'm making a simple Tic-Tac-Toe game to learn Haskell.  Each cell in the board has either a player value (X or O) or a positional value if the square is empty (letters A-I, such that:

```
A|B|C
D|E|F
G|H|I
```

)

To start, I've created a simple function that takes an empty board (which looks like the one above) and a String (a letter "A" through "I"), and returns a board where the letter entered is replaced with an "X".  So if I were to call `newBoard blankBoard "C"`, I would expect this to return:

```
A|B|X
D|E|F
G|H|I
```

If I want to keep the `Square` data type as it is, how could I make this code work:

```
data Square = A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | X | O deriving (Read)
instance Show Square where
  show A = "A"
  show B = "B"
  show C = "C"
  show D = "D"
  show E = "E"
  show F = "F"
  show G = "G"
  show H = "H"
  show I = "I"
type Board = [[Square]]

blankBoard :: Board
blankBoard = [[A,B,C],[D,E,F],[G,H,I]]

newBoard :: Board -> String -> Board
newBoard board letter = [[ if show sq == letter then X else sq | sq <- row ]| row <- board]
```

I'm getting this error, and not sure why:

```
[[*** Exception: myfunctions.hs:(386,3)-(394,14): Non-exhaustive patterns in function show
```

Comment: You are trying to use show on an X or an O, which is something that you haven't defined. Is there a reason that you don't just use `deriving Show` for your Square?

Comment: That did the trick, thanks!  I didn't realize that X was being shown.

Comment: Enabling warnings would have found this bug at compile time.

Comment: @JHobern, can you make your comment an answer, so OP can accept? Also, OP, why are you using == on String, not on Square, simply deriving Eq?

Answer (score 1):

The error `Non-exhaustive patterns in function` means that you have tried to use a function with an argument for which it wasn't defined. In this case, you have tried to use `show` on either an `X` or an `O`, whereas you have only defined it for `A` through `I`.

You could fix this by adding:

```
show X = "X"
show O = "O"
```

However, since your `show` function doesn't do anything special at all, you would be better off just using `deriving Show`, and letting Haskell create the function for you.